Quarkus 2.16.10.Final OIDC multi-tenancy by annotation - failing with RoutingContext failure (500) in prod deployment
I have implemented multi-tenancy in a Quarkus 2.16.10.Final app with Keycloak as ID Provider as described here
https://quarkus.io/version/2.16/guides/security-openid-connect-multitenancy
using annotations as the requirement is pretty basic (we need to have a second realm with passwords that never expire for one "technical" API (i.e., an API not called by human users)).
This works fine in the dev environment with a local Keycloak standalone server containing the second realm, and a Quarkus config that looks something like this
##############################################
# Quarkus OIDC configuration
##############################################

quarkus.http.auth.proactive=false

quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url = http://127.0.0.1:8180/realms/<DEFAULT_REALM_NAME>
quarkus.oidc.token.issuer = http://127.0.0.1:8180/realms/<DEFAULT_REALM_NAME>
quarkus.oidc.client-id = <DEFAULT_REALM_CLIENT_NAME>
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret = <DEFAULT_REALM_CLIENT_SECRET>
quarkus.oidc.application-type = service

quarkus.oidc.test.auth-server-url = http://127.0.0.1:8180/realms/<SECOND_REALM_NAME>
quarkus.oidc.test.token.issuer=http://127.0.0.1:8180/realms/<SECOND_REALM_NAME>
quarkus.oidc.test.client-id = <SECOND_REALM_CLIENT_NAME>
quarkus.oidc.test.credentials.secret = <SECOND_REALM_CLIENT_SECRET>
quarkus.oidc.test.application-type = service

Calling the API with a curl request containing a JWT token.
However, when I move to production mode, Quarkus fails to use the "test" realm.
In the log I have
2024-05-02 13:21:42,329 DEBUG [io.qua.oid.run.OidcProviderClient] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) Get token on: https://<KEYCLOAK_SERVICE_NAME>.<NAMESPACE>.svc.cluster.local:8443/auth/realms/<DEFAULT_REALM_NAME>/protocol/openid-connect/token

-> wrong Realm (request going to the default Realm)
followed by
"description":"RoutingContext failure (500)","stacktrace":"io.quarkus.security.AuthenticationFailedException\n\tat io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcIdentityProvider$6.apply(OidcIdentityProvider.java:227)\n\tat io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcIdentityProvider$6.apply(OidcIdentityProvider.java:223) ...

Just to confirm the behaviour, I put the settings of the second realm in the default realm parameters, and the API call works, so there is not issue with the values for quarkus.oidc.test.* parameters.
Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong, or is there some know issue implementing multi-tenancy by annotation on Quarkus 2.16.10.Final?
Thanks

The reason it may be working with web-app is likely to do with the fact there are some extra checks related to the tenant identification. Unfortunately, no more 2.16.x releases are expected so please move to one of the newest Quarkus releases. A lot of updates have been made in the tenant resolution area since 2.16

Hi @SergeyBeryozkin, we finally upgraded to 3.10.0 - it was less painful than expected, thanks. Using the Tenant annotation provided in this version worked fine. Thanks
